# jquery and selecbox, disallowing

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

```
$('#my_select').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //return false also fails.
    alert("test"); //or show my dialog
});
```

Having a such live action, I want to disable how dropdown options appear once I click the selectbox, instead I want to display my own div which changes the value. However the code above doesn't disallow it and I don't want to used `disabled= "disabled"` attribute as it fails for further server based validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/MhTet/

This should help you :)

in case link broken :)

```
$('select').live("mousedown", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //return false also fails.
    //alert("test"); //or show my dialog
    return;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That is not really possible. If you really have to do this (consider the impact to accessibly!), then you'l need to replace the whole `select` element. There are several ready made JavaScript libraries that can do that for you.